Configurar entorno Intellijs en VSCode
buenas. Tengo configurado el entorno intellijs para correr java + maven + springboot, pero quiero correrlo por comodidad directamente en VSCode, ¿como puedo configurar el build y run con cus variables de ambiente en VSCode?
Gracias!

que has intentado? La consola interna nunca falla :D
